# Inconsistent spacing in list items AND list not responding to margin/padding?

Tags: navigation, css-float, alignment, margin

Okay, quite a noob when it comes to HTML but I'm having a bit of a problem.

I'm trying to get my links in a decent place. Here's a breakdown.
I've defined a container that is 960px wide that I've put inside my header.
Inside that container, I have an image which is my logo and an unordered list, the logo is aligning perfectly with a bit of space between it and the edge of the left side of the page, however the list is aligning to the right, right up to the edge of the page no matter how much I change the right margin/padding.

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="container">
    <img src="images/headerlogo.jpg" height="240" width="381" />
        <ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="index.html"><b>.home</b></a></li>
            <li><a href="blog.html"><b>.blog</b></a><li>
            <li><a href="portfolio.html"><b>.portfolio</b></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the CSS to accompany the elements.

```
/* Common Classes */
.container {width:960px;margin:0 auto;}

/* Header */
#header {
height:240px;
background:url(../images/headerbg.jpg) repeat-x; margin:0;
    }
#nav {list-style:none; margin:190px 0 0 0; padding:0; float:right;}
#nav li {float:left; height:45px; text-align: center; padding:7px 1px 5px 5px; margin:0 0 5px 5px;}
#nav li a {color:#a4b2b7; font-family:arial; font-size:25pt; letter-spacing:-2px; text-decoration:none;}
#nav li a:hover {color:#2f738c;}
```

EDIT: Also, the third list item is spacing itself farther away than the first two... as if it has a margin on the left of that individual item... why? >_<

Have I completely missed something? Anything else you need just let me know.

Any help is appreciated, thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't close second `<li>` item and that is why you have a space between second and third element.
It should be:  `<li><a href="blog.html"><b>.blog</b></a></li>`.

But when I'm giving the `margin-right: 10px;` for `#nav` I get 10px space from the right...

Comment: God I really need some sleep haha, thanks alot. Just quickly, I was led to believe that margin: top bottom left right (margin: 0 0 0 0) was how to set a margin-right value, i.e by editing the fourth value. This didn't work, which is why I was confused, however using margin-right worked perfectly for which I will thank you again! :)

Comment: No problem, but you can use just margin `margin:190px 100px 0 0;` To have top and right margin ;) Cheers